# How to take the backup of SPList having MMS Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

How to take the backup of SPList having MMS Column? If I take the .stp file from the list settings I can not get this managed metadata column after taking the template file. Any other way I can get the backup of this SPList, either through PowerShell or through SP Object Model.

Comment: Are you restoring the List Template in the same farm?

Comment: Yes Amal, I am trying to restore the list in the same farm. I have this requirement wherein I am filling this list from a excel file with some 1200 records and one of the columns is MMS column. So now, customer has given us a new excel file of  some 2000 records to be populated.So I want to take the backup of  this SPList including this MMS column before populating the new excel records.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access Central Administration you can backup your list in **Backup and Restore** - **Export a site or list** (*Granular Backup* section). 
Hope this will help you.